# How do I print from a vector of vectors in java

Tags: java, vector, collections

I just started Java Programming. I am doing some questions from the Programming Challenges Book. The question was to print out the maximum cyclelength of a given set of integers. Here is my code:

```
public class JavaApplication9 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("This is a program that calculates the maximum"
                + " cyclelength of two integers between 1 and 1000000");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
        int x = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
        int y = keyboard.nextInt();
        @SuppressWarnings("UseOfObsoleteCollectionType")
        Vector<Integer> cycleVec = new Vector<Integer>();
        Vector newVec = new Vector(); 
        if (x <= 0 || y <= 0 || x >= 1000000 || y >= 1000000)
            System.out.println("Wrong input. Input must be greater than 0"
               + " and less than 1,000,000!!");
        else{
            for(int k = Math.min(x, y);k<=Math.max(x, y);k++){
                   // We have to count 1 also
                   cycleVec.add(1 + cycleLength(k));  
                   newVec.add(numList(k));
            }
            Enumeration vEnum = cycleVec.elements();
            while(vEnum.hasMoreElements()){
                int a = (int) vEnum.nextElement();
                display(newVec, x, y, a);
            }
            System.out.println("\nElements in vector of cyclelengths:");
            while(vEnum.hasMoreElements())
                System.out.print(vEnum.nextElement() + " ");
            System.out.println();
            Object obj = Collections.max(cycleVec);
            System.out.printf("%d %d ", x, y);
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
    }

    public static int cycleLength(int x){
        int termPoint = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (termPoint != 1){
            if (x % 2 == 0){
                x = x/2;
                termPoint = x;
            }else{
                x = x*3 + 1;
                termPoint = x;
            }
            ++count;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static Vector numList(int x){
        int termPoint = 0;
        Vector vec = new Vector();
        while (termPoint != 1){
            if (x % 2 == 0){
                x = x/2;
                termPoint = x;
            }else{
                x = x*3 + 1;
                termPoint = x;
            }
            vec.addElement(x);
        }
        return vec;
    }

    public static void display(Vector v, int x, int y, int size){
        System.out.println("Elements generated:");
        int m = 0;
        for(int k = Math.min(x, y); k <= Math.max(x, y); k++){
            System.out.print("Number " + k + " ");
            for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
                    m = (int)((Vector)v.elementAt(i)).elementAt(j);
                    System.out.print(m + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
run:
This is a program that calculates the maximum cyclelength of two integers between 1 and 1000000
Enter the first number: 201

Enter the second number: 210
Elements generated:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18 >= 18
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
Number 201604 302 151 454 227 682 341 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1     at javaapplication9.JavaApplication9.display(JavaApplication9.java:95)
    at javaapplication9.JavaApplication9.main(JavaApplication9.java:44)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

The first part of the code works (if you remove the display function). I just wanted to print out for each integer x, the list of integers generated and the list of cyclelengths and the maximum cyclelength. Also is there a way I can make this code more efficient (reduce the number of lines of code)?

The new code for the display(It works)

```
 public static void display(Vector v){
        System.out.println("Elements generated:");
        int m = 0, w = 0;     
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
            Vector inner = (Vector)v.elementAt(i);
            System.out.println("Number ");
            for (int j = 0; j < inner.size(); j++){
                m = (int)inner.elementAt(j);
                if (j == 0){
                    if (m % 2 == 0){
                        w = (m-1)/3;
                    }else{
                        w = m * 2;
                    }
                System.out.print(w + " ");
                }
                System.out.print(m + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you're using a `Vector`? It synchronizes on every action, and it doesn't even seem like you're multithreading. From the [class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html): "*Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector.*"

Comment: Thanks. So how do I use an ArrayList then?

Comment: Just like a `Vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `display` method's last parameter is an integer being used as the size of the inner vector, however back at the top we see it's actually one larger than the size because of this line:

```
// We have to count 1 also
cycleVec.add(1 + cycleLength(k));
```

You need to think about what the `cycleVec` values are being used for an the correct limit for looping through the vections in the `display` method.

The exception means that you are trying to access more entries in a vector than it has.  You have two calls to `elementAt` on the same line. It looks like it's the second reference that's failing. That means `j` is too large, which means the `size` parameter is not right. The safe way to access the inner array would be like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
    Vector inner = (Vector)v.elementAt(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < inner.size(); j++) {
        m = (int)inner.elementAt(j);
        System.out.print(m + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The cycleVec values hold the count of the each cycleLength operation. So I stored these values in a vector which is an Element of newVec. Basically, newVec.size() are the rows and the each of the element of cycleVec is the number of columns.

Comment: I removed the one in cycleVec.add(1 + cycleLength(k)). The output is:

Enter the first number: 10

Enter the second number: 30
Elements generated:
Number 10 5 16 8 4 2 1 
34 17 52 26 13 40 
6 3 10 5 16 8 
40 20 10 5 16 8 
7 22 11 34 17 52 
46 23 70 35 106 53 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 4
8 4 2 1  at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
 at javaapplication9.JavaApplication9.display(JavaApplication9.java:95)
 at javaapplication9.JavaApplication9.main(JavaApplication9.java:44)
Java Result: 1

Comment: adding more info to the answer